# Wodrpress Gravity Forms How To Attach Multiple Files From Media Library

Tags: php, gravity-forms-plugin

The idea is that we are programmatically trying to attach x number of attachments using Gravity Forms to the notification object retrieved from the wordpress media library. These attachments are determined programmatically according to what selections the user specified in the form filling stage.

In GFORM_NOTIFICATION event I am attaching a single file from the Wordpress library to an email notification. My client has asked me to show a proof of concept that we can programmatically attach multiple files.

so before my working code to attach one file looked like this:

```
$attachment = get_attached_file($file1);
$notification [‘attachments’][] = $attachment;
```

my new code to attach 2 files is not working. it is only attaching one file (file2). what is wrong with this please why will it not attach multiple files to the email notification???

```
$notification[‘attachments’] = array();
$notification[‘attachments’][] = get_attached_file($file1);|
$notification[‘attachments’][] = get_attached_file($file2);|
```